# UWP animate scrollviewer horizontal offset with double animation c#

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, doubleanimation

how can we move the horizontal offset of ScrollViewer in xaml c# DoubleAnimation

```
 DoubleAnimation verticalAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

 verticalAnimation.From = 0;
 verticalAnimation.To = 87;
 verticalAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);       

 storyboard = new Storyboard();

 storyboard.Children.Add(verticalAnimation);
 Storyboard.SetTarget(verticalAnimation, scrolviewer);
 Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(verticalAnimation, "HorizontalOffset");
 storyboard.Begin();
```

the above code is not working

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong here (except that you called it "verticalAnimation" when it's moving the horizontal offset). Does it show any error that might help? Look at the debug output window when debugging. Errors in xaml are usually printed to it.

Comment: HorizontalOffset is GET only  dependency Property so can't be directly animate like you are doing. I'd suggest creating a dummy property and animate that - and in it's PropertyChanged callback, use ScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset method to actually update the scroll